# I am making a react native app in which I want to make payments through POS via NFC. But I am facing error in getting data through NFC

Tags: reactjs, react-native, nfc, point-of-sale, react-native-nfc-manager

I am making a react native app in which I want to make payments through POS via NFC. But I am facing error in getting data through NFC. I have used react-native-nfc-manager, it is making sure that my device has NFC support but not giving me the data when I bring my device near the POS.

I tried this code ,

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, Button, Alert } from "react-native";
import NfcManager, { NfcEvents, NdefParser } from "react-native-nfc-manager";

const App = () => {
  const [nfcData, setNfcData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Function to check NFC support
    const checkNfcSupport = async () => {
      try {
        // Check if NFC is supported
        const isSupported = await NfcManager.isSupported();
        if (isSupported) {
          console.log("NFC is supported on this device");
          // Initialize NFC manager
          await NfcManager.start();
          // Add NFC tag detection event listener
          NfcManager.setEventListener(NfcEvents.DiscoverTag, async (tag) => {
            console.log("Scanned NFC Tag:", tag);
            Alert.alert("Scanned NFC Tag:", tag);
            if (tag.ndefMessage && tag.ndefMessage.length > 0) {
              const parsedNdefMessage = NdefParser.parseTextPayload(
                tag.ndefMessage[0].payload
              );
              console.log("NFC Tag Data:", parsedNdefMessage);
              setNfcData(parsedNdefMessage);
            }
            // Close the NFC session
            NfcManager.setAlertMessageIOS("NFC tag scanned");
            await NfcManager.unregisterTagEvent();
          });
        } else {
          console.log("NFC is not supported on this device");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error checking NFC support:", error);
      }
    };

    // Call the function to check NFC support
    checkNfcSupport();

    // Clean up NFC manager on unmount
    return () => {
      NfcManager.setEventListener(NfcEvents.DiscoverTag, null);
      NfcManager.unregisterTagEvent().catch(() => {});
      NfcManager.cancelTechnologyRequest().catch(() => {});
      NfcManager.disable().catch(() => {});
    };
  }, []);

  // Function to handle Scan NFC Tag button press
  const handleScanNfcTag = async () => {
    try {
      // Check if NFC is supported
      const isSupported = await NfcManager.isSupported();
      if (isSupported) {
        // Enable NFC scanning
        await NfcManager.registerTagEvent();
        setNfcData(null);
      } else {
        console.log("NFC is not supported on this device");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error checking NFC support:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Checking NFC Support</Text>
      <Button title="Scan NFC Tag" onPress={handleScanNfcTag} />
      {nfcData && (
        <View>
          <Text>NFC Tag Data:</Text>
          <Text>{JSON.stringify(nfcData)}</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a number of problems.

1. You don't specify a platform but you have some iOS specific code and Apple do not allow normal developer to do anything related to payments (on Android you can)
2. The code trying to use the NFC hardware as an NFC reader and the POS device is also a NFC Reader, 2 devices acting as readers cannot communicate to each other, one device must be a reader and the other device NFC hardware must act are a NFC Tag (a contactless bank card acts as a NFC Tag). In NFC terms you must have an initiator (reader) and a target (Tag). Some NFC hardware (a lot of phones or some USB readers) can act as a reader or Tag but probably a POS can only act as a reader.
3. Apple don't also anybody to use their hardware to behave like a Tag other than themselves. On Android it is possible with Host Card Emulation (HCE)
4. You are trying to do stuff with the Ndef data format, all payment related stuff does not use the Ndef data format.

So in summary, what you are trying to do is impossible on iOS and very complicated on Android (especially in react-native, you would have to write native Java\Kotlin code)

Comment: So, How could I communicate between POS and react native app using NFC to make payment ?