# I am making a react-native app but facing some issues in making contactless payments via NFC to various POS

Tags: node.js, react-native, nfc, point-of-sale, clover-payment

I am making a digital wallet app like apple pay or google pay and wondering how can I make NFC payment with all POS.

I am making a payment app like apple pay or google pay but facing some issues in using contactless payments via NFC to various POS.
I tried to integrate Clover but then I realized if I do so, then my app will be able to do transaction with the Clover POS only. But I want to do transactions with all different company's POS, i.e., Lightspeed, Moneris, Verifone, etc.
If anyone know how do apps and POS communicate to make transaction, it would be a great help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am making a react native app in which I want to make payments through POS via NFC. But I am facing error in getting data through NFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76122746/i-am-making-a-react-native-app-in-which-i-want-to-make-payments-through-pos-via)